# Hash classnames nextJS v14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, hash

How do you hash CSS class names for nextJS v14?

The old way you used to do that was something like:

```
const path = require("path");
const loaderUtils = require("loader-utils");

const hashOnlyIdent = (context, _, exportName) =>
  loaderUtils
    .getHashDigest(
      Buffer.from(
        `filePath:${path
          .relative(context.rootContext, context.resourcePath)
          .replace(/\\+/g, "/")}#className:${exportName}`
      ),
      "md4",
      "base64",
      6
    )
    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/g, "_")
    .replace(/^(-?\d|--)/, "_$1");

module.exports = {
  experimental: { appDir: true },
  webpack(config, { dev }) {
    const rules = config.module.rules
      .find((rule) => typeof rule.oneOf === "object")
      .oneOf.filter((rule) => Array.isArray(rule.use));
    if (!dev)
      rules.forEach((rule) => {
        rule.use.forEach((moduleLoader) => {
          if (
            moduleLoader.loader?.includes("css-loader") &&
            !moduleLoader.loader?.includes("postcss-loader")
          )
            moduleLoader.options.modules.getLocalIdent = hashOnlyIdent;
        });
      });

    return config;
  },
};
```

But this currently gives some errors. Like: `getLocalIdent is not found`.

You can directly use `className={styles.flag}` inside of your JSX file but this doesn't hash it to a short code in production (like vercel).

So I want, as a result, to have my CSS classnames look like this: `9pt5S` instead of the current `navbar_flag__9pt5S` (by using: `className={styles.flag}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, similar to the old solution:

```
import loaderUtils from "loader-utils";
import path from "path";

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

const cssModuleLocalIdent = (context, _, exportName, options) => {
    const relativePath = path.relative(context.rootContext, context.resourcePath).replace(/\\+/g, "/");
    const hash = loaderUtils.getHashDigest(Buffer.from(`filePath:${relativePath}#className:${exportName}`), "sha1", "base64", 5);
    return loaderUtils.interpolateName(context, hash, options).replace(
      /\.module_/, "_")
      .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/g, "_")
      .replace(/^(\d|--|-\d)/, "__$1");
}

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    const rules = config.module.rules
      .find((rule) => typeof rule.oneOf === 'object')
      .oneOf.filter((rule) => Array.isArray(rule.use));

    if (isProd) {
      rules.forEach((rule) => {
        rule.use.forEach((moduleLoader) => {
          if (
            moduleLoader.loader?.includes('css-loader')
            && !moduleLoader.loader?.includes('postcss-loader')
            && moduleLoader.options.modules
          ) {
            moduleLoader.options.modules.getLocalIdent = cssModuleLocalIdent;
          }
        });
      });
    }

    return config;
  },
}

export default nextConfig
```

Make sure you have the "loader-utils" and "path" modules installed.